# how to execute multiple animations in a row on the same UIImageView

Tags: iphone, animation, uiimageview

I'd like to do two animations, one after the other:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"growImage" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.2f];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
image6.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.9, 0.9);
[UIView commitAnimations];

[UIView beginAnimations:@"shrinkImage" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5f];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
image6.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.1, 0.1);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

I know that I can do the second animation in

```
- (void)animationDidStop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context {
```

or by setting a

```
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(shrinkImage)];
```

But is there a way that I can pass in the value (in this case a UIIMageView named image6) so that the second animation occurs on the same object as the first one?

THANKS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the selector-based approach, the selector that you specify in the `setAnimationDidStopSelector` gets passed a `context` parameter that you specify in your `beginAnimations:context:` call.

So, if you change your beginAnimations call to:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"growImage" context:image6];
```

then `image6` will get passed as the context parameter to your selector.

An easier way would be to use blocks to accomplish the same thing:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^() {
    image6.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.9, 0.9);
}
completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^() {
        image6.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.1, 0.1);
    }];
}];
```

Comment: Perfect - thank you!  I also had to change - (void)animationDidStop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context { to - (void)animationDidStop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(UIImageView *)context {

Answer (score 1):

This is an example from my code. But you get the idea. You need to use `CGAffineTransformConcat` to stitch multiple  animation together. You can do this-

```
   [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
    angle             = 0;
    scaleFactor       = 1;
    startPoint.x      = 60.0;
    startPoint.y      = 60.0;
    CGAffineTransform scaleTrans  = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
    CGAffineTransform rotateTrans = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle * M_PI/180);
    boxView.center    = startPoint;
    boxView.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(scaleTrans, rotateTrans);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

iOS4 has [**Single block animation**](http://pragmaticstudio.com/blog/2010/7/28/ios4-blocks-1) you could use that instead of Two Block animation. Apple documentation states that Single Block animation is more smooth, plus its easy to stitch multiple animations one after the other...

**UPDATE:** After thinking more carefully, you could do this -

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 
                      delay:0 
                    options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut 
                 animations:^{ /* first level of animation */
                 } 
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                 }
];
```

As you can see, after the animation completes, you can start another animation or you can clean up. This block based animation, is used to chain animations together...

Comment: Thanks for commenting. This looks like you are scaling AND rotating at the same time.  I am looking to grow the image, and then when that animation is complete, I want to shrink the image back down - I can't have both grow and shrink happen at the same time like you do with scaling and rotating...

Comment: I love the idea of this block based animation, but in using your code I am getting an error - Incompatible block pointer types initializing 'void (^)()', expected 'void (^)(void)'

Comment: CAUTION: I have typed it free-hand. There might be typos! Please refer Apple docs or other online docs... Glad I could help.

Comment: Thanks - I awarded the correct answer to @highlycaffeinated since he taught me how to pass a value using context into animationDidStop. He also suggested block based animation as you did. I'm going to be using these, I'm very excited that this exists, although I need to learn a bit more about the proper code to get this to work - Thank You!

Comment: one note to keep in mind that I just found online - this is only available in iOS4, so if someone is running an iPad with 3.2 or an iPhone pre-iOS4 this will likely crash the app. That's unfortunate.